# GCD of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, noncommutative-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

Given $A=M_1SN_1$ and $B=M_2SN_2$ where all $M_1,M_2,S,N_1,N_2\in\Bbb Z_{\geq0}^{n\times n}$ are all symmetric full rank is there a procedure to extract $S$ from $A$ and $B$ using gcd like operations?

Comment: Sadly, the answer must be no. Most obviously, suppose $M_1$ is the zero matrix. Then, $S$ could be anything. Of course, even if you eliminate this trivial case, similar things happen; there is a question of rank.

Comment: Are $M_i$  and $N_i$ given?

Comment: @IgorRivin No that defeats the purpose of problem.

Comment: In that case, as @D.Wagner would say, life is sad indeed, since $S$ could be the identity, and then you would have $M_i$ and $N_i$ be indeterminate at least up to elements of $GL(n, \mathbb{Z}).$

Comment: @IgorRivin gcd computation can return $1$

Comment: You are asking for all ways to factor a matrix. That is obviously ridiculous.

Comment: @IgorRivin I do not think so. I think $\Bbb Z_{\geq0}^{n\times n}$ should force a constraint.

Comment: @IgorRivin: Because the question concerns *integer* matrices, it isn't obvious to me that sense cannot be made of finding, up to equivalence, a common matrix "factor" $S$ of given $A$ and $B$.  Perhaps the OP would benefit from an explanation of [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) in this connection.

Comment: @hardmath $gcd(M_1SN_1,M_2SN_2)=gcd(M_1AA^{-1}SBB^{-1}N_1,M_2AA^{-1}SN_2)=S=AA^{-1}S$. I do not think the problem is ambiguous even without symmetry condition. Since we are in $\Bbb Z$ there should be no ambiguity. Correct?

Comment: @hardmath I am missing some intuitive example here. Why do you say $S$ is not unique?

Comment: @Arul:  Regardless of what symmetric integer matrices $A,B$ are chosen, we can express both $A = M_1 S N_1$ and $B = M_2 S N_2$ as products of symmetric matrices where $S$ is any symmetric invertible integer matrix such as the identity or the antidiagonal permutation matrix.

Comment: @hardmath could you modify problem to what you think is reasonable?

Comment: @Arul:  Without knowing what motivates your question, it is hard for me make such a modification without changing the problem substantially.  If you were to abandon the concern for symmetry of matrices, but require that $S$ be diagonal, then a case could be for defining $S$ as "greatest common divisor" of the Smith normal forms $S_1$ and $S_2$ of $A,B$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

OK, $M_1=T_1H$, $M_2=T_2H$, where $T_1, T_2, H$ have a full rank. Where is answer $HS$ or $H$ or $S$? We can't do this(

Comment: in this case what is $S$? We would need $gcd(T_1H,T_2H)=H$

Comment: Fix the problem, and after I'll delete it

Comment: this problem cannot be fixed.

Comment: Real definition of $gcd(a,b)$ is such $d$ that:(1) $d|a$, $d|b$ and (2) for any $d'$, if $d'|a$, $d'|b$ than $d'|d$. You can fix your problem as (may be): "your problem text" for any such representation and corresponding matrix $S'$ there exists $U,V$ such that $S=US'V$.